# Gradle for Golang (Use/build some .go within Java project)

Tags: go, gradle

Is Go supported by Gradle? How to start?

I am starting my research, but so far I only find 1 plugin on https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=go

1. https://github.com/echocat/gradle-golang-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, gradle or maven would *not* be needed, because:

- [`go build`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) is enough.
- the dependencies are managed by go itself.

You see some project using Makefile (to link `go build` and `go test` and `go vet`).

Answer (score 2):

Try Gogradle https://github.com/blindpirate/gogradle, a full featured plugin for Golang.

The reason why we need it is that Golang lacks of automatic build mechanism,  package versioning and many other stuff which is supported by Gogradle.